# Jquery V[g].exec is not a function when append

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, append

I try to make a script that appends table into a div (div is in site). I use function:

```
function makeTable(container, data) {
var table = $("<table/>");
$.each(data, function (rowIndex, r) {
    var row = $("<tr/>");
    $.each(r, function (colIndex, c) {
        row.append($("<t" + (rowIndex === -1 ? "h" : "d") + "/>").append(c));
    });
    table.append(row);
});
return container.append(table);}
```

It works fine on Firefox and Yandex Browser, but not on Slimjet.
My table looks like this:

```
    var kw_time_input = $('<input>').attr('id', 'kwtime_i').attr('checked', GM_getValue(nick_p + link_id + 'kwtime')).attr('type', 'checkbox');
var own_kw_time_input = $('<input>').attr('id', 'ownkwtime_i').attr('checked', GM_getValue(nick_p + link_id + 'ownkwtime')).attr('type', 'checkbox');
var kw_bg_color_select = $('<select>').attr('id', 'kw_bg_color_select').attr('class', 'combobox').css('display', 'flex').css('width', 'auto').attr('style', 'text-align-last: center; text-align: center;').css('color', GM_getValue(nick_p + link_id + 'kw_bg_color_select_last'));
var kw_text_color_select = $('<select>').attr('id', 'kw_text_color_select').attr('class', 'combobox').css('display', 'flex').css('width', 'auto').attr('style', 'text-align-last: center; text-align: center;').css('color', GM_getValue(nick_p + link_id + 'kw_text_color_select_last'));
var okw_bg_color_select = $('<select>').attr('id', 'okw_bg_color_select').attr('class', 'combobox').css('display', 'flex').css('width', 'auto').attr('style', 'text-align-last: center; text-align: center;').css('color', GM_getValue(nick_p + link_id + 'okw_bg_color_select_last'));
var okw_text_color_select = $('<select>').attr('id', 'okw_text_color_select').attr('class', 'combobox').css('display', 'flex').css('width', 'auto').attr('style', 'text-align-last: center; text-align: center;').css('color', GM_getValue(nick_p + link_id + 'okw_text_color_select_last'));
var kw_settings_arr = [
    ["Czas do zakończenia najbliższego KW do którego dołączysz", kw_time_input, "Kolor tła:", kw_bg_color_select, "Kolor czcionki:", kw_text_color_select],
    ["Czas do zakończenia założonego KW", own_kw_time_input, "Kolor tła:", okw_bg_color_select, "Kolor czcionki:", okw_text_color_select]
];
makeTable($("#3"), kw_settings_arr);
```

I can't append `table.append(row);` but I don't know why?
What's wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is in `var table = $("<table/>");` When I try to make `var table = $("<div/>");` it works, and append `row` without problem. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
`var table = $("<table/>").append('<tbody/>');`
and
`$('tbody', table).append(row);`
To be vailid HTML string/object.